# SSIS filename - file count

Tags: sql, ssis

I'm currently creating a `flat file export` for one of our clients, i've managed to get the file in the format they want, i'm trying to get the easiest way of creating a `dynamic` file name. I've got the date in as a variable and the path ect but they want a count in the file name. For example

File name 1 : `TDY_11-02-2013_{1}_T1.txt`. The `{}` being the count. So next weeks file would be `TDY_17-02-2013_{2}_T1.txt`

I cant see an easy way of doing this!! any idea's??

Comment: Use a execute SQL statement to get the count and store it into a variable and concate that variable in the file name.

Comment: I need to store a list of the counts in a table wouldn't I?

Comment: So you wanted to store the file's count not row count. Correct? Sorry, I didn't notice the title well.

Comment: Yes you can store the file count in a table and use it.

Comment: Still struggling to find a way of doing this as its just the file name that needs to change.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:
on my first answer, I thought you meant count of values returned on a query. My bad!
two ways to achieve this, you could loop into the destination folder, select the last file by date, get its value and increase 1, which sound like a lot of trouble. Why not a simple log table on the DB with last execution date and ID and then you compose your file name base on the last row of this table?

where exactly is your problem?

you can make a dynamic file name using expressions:

[image]

the count, you can use a "row count" component inside your data flow to assign the result to a variable and use the variable on your expression:

[image]

Comment: The problem is where as it’s easy to get a variable date into the file name a continuous count which increases from what the last file was is not. I effectively need to count on a variable which changes week on week with no reference to the previous file. So using a standard variable name doesn’t seem like an option.

Answer (score 0):

Use Script task and get the number inside the curly braces of the file name and store it in a variable.
Create  a variable(`FileNo of type int`) which stores the number for the file

Pseudo code

```
  string name = string.Empty;
  string loction = @"D:\";

 /* Get the path from the connection manager like the code below
    instead of hard coding like D: above
   string flatFileConn = 
   (string(Dts.Connections["Yourfile"].AcquireConnection(null) as String);
 */
  string pattern = string.Empty;
  int number = 0;
  string pattern = @"{([0-9])}"; // Not sure about the correct regular expression to retrieve the number inside braces
  foreach (string  s in Directory.GetFiles(loction,"*.txt"))
     {
        name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(s);
        Match match = Regex.Match(name, pattern );
          if (match.Success)
           {
             dts.Variables["User::FileNo"].Value = int.Parse(match.Value)+1;
           }
     }
```

Now once you get the value use it in your file expression in the connection manager

```
@[User::FilePath] +@[User::FileName]
                             +"_{"+ (DT_STR,10,1252) @[User::FileNo] + "}T1.txt"
```

Comment: I can see what your getting at here but I'm struggling to put this into practice!